# Newly added jap page requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an existing MVC application that uses the following Dispatcher:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What I did was under the WEB-INF/views directory add a menu.jsp file to be the new startup jsp.

```
/SpringMvcJdbcTemplate/WEB-INF/views/menu.jsp
```

New menu.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Main Menu</h1>
        <h3><a href="listContact">List Contacts</a></h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now what I did is change the initial "/" RequestMapping controller method to look like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView menu(ModelAndView model){
    model.setViewName("menu");

    return model;
}
```

Now I feel that everything should work but when I run the application I receive the following page errors:

HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMvcJdbcTemplate/WEB-INF/views/menu.jsp

type Status report

message /SpringMvcJdbcTemplate/WEB-INF/views/menu.jsp

description The requested resource is not available

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something dumb. I misspelled "menu" as "meun". Renamed and now all is better.